# Where am I going wrong in this python code for CLRS exercise 2.1-4

Tags: python, binary, addition, clrs

So the problem is:
"Consider a problem of adding two n-bit binary integers, stored in two n-element arrays A and B. The sum of the two integers should be stored in binary form in an (n+1)-element array C. State the problem formally and write pseudocode for adding the two integers."

and my python code for this problem is:

```
A = [1,0,1,1,0,1,0]
B = [1,1,1,0,1,0,0]
n = len(A)
C = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

for i in range(0, n):
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i] + C[i]
    if C[i] == 2:
        C[i] = 0
        C[i+1] == 1
    elif C[i] == 3:
        C[i] = 1
        C[i+1] = 1


print C
```

Also I have taken the **least significant digits on the left** which I can reverse after I've done the calculation.

I cant figure out what the mistake is please help!

Comment: Just a note:

If you plan on having A & B taken in via input, an easier way to define `C` would be `C=[0]*(n+1)`, which auto generates the array you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C[i+1] == 1` does a *comparison*, **not** an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In case, you like a slight modification for the sake of brevity (pseudocode):

```
for i = C.length to i = 2
  C[i] = C[i] + A[i-1] + B[i-1]
  if C[i] > 1
    C[i-1] = C[i-1] + 1
    C[i] = C[i] - 2
```